# Extracting multiple text data from a single attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to extract a few fields of data from a single attribute from a single selector. What I mean by that is, all of the information I'm trying to scrape is in parts of the site I can get this way:

```
response.css('td::attr(onclick)').get()
```

when I run that, I receive:

```
handler(this, "HANDLE", {"asdf":"5777","zxcv":"754401863","hjkl":"666","tyui":"277371661","name":"lolol","something":"someth1ng","type":"animal","genre":"javasux"});return false;'
```

and let's say the Scrapy Items I'm trying to create have fields a, b and c, where I would like a to be the value of "hjkl" of the above exerpt (666), b to be value of "name" (lolol), and c to be value of "asdf" (5777).

Where in the **scraper**/project should I include the logic that would do this? Because I think sadly I can't "get" the values from these fields like asdf using selectors so I would have to use item loaders/item processors, is that correct? And I assume the actual selection would have to be done using regexp? I'm asking because while in this particular project scraping a single site will be relatively simple, I have  of those sites to go through, and regular expressions aren't too fast from what I understand.

Comment: This looks like a dict & accessing using key's would be easier than using a regex.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html#topics-parsing-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think regex would be the simpler solution, in the end that's just a long string so you can also clean it to get only the information that you need, and maybe just get the part that looks like a dictionary and `json` it.

Another way would be to use a javascript parser because that's what you have inside that string. You can use [js2xml](https://github.com/scrapinghub/js2xml) for that.